# Facebook API Send dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, send

Here is my send javascript code:

```
function send(id, description, title) {
        FB.ui({
            app_id: '390841657651335',
            method: 'send',
            description: description,
            link: http://vic.bg/Vits.aspx?vicid=' + id,
            name: title
        }
    }
```

Send is always ok (i dumped the response from the callback to the console), but recients got that message

**Attachment Unavailable This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you**

instead of the actual post. Did someone face that problem?

Comment: Your have syntax error (missing apostrophe before link). Otherwise it works as expected for me... BTW, you are not required to provide app_id property if using official SDK.

Comment: i accedently deleted that apostrophe during the post preratation :)

Comment: and app_id is one of my desperate attempts to make it work :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem was with the settings of the application Sandbox Mode: was checked. 
I do not know why they display such strange message in that case

Answer (score 0):

So, did the 'send dialog' worked for you? because from all of my research and reading all posts related, facebook currently doesn't allow to send private messages to friends through graph api..

I'm trying the 'send dialog' via a direct URL and not via JS SDK.